# .NET Core absolute links point to localhost

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core

I'm on a Ubuntu 16.04 and I have Kestrel server running on the vm.
Whole traffic is redirected there using nginx as a reverse-proxy.

My WebHost looks like this:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
```

When I try to get full url to an action using this method:

```
Url.Action("Index", "User", null, HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
```

It's returning address for localhost instead of domain.

So instead of:

> hxxp://domain.com/user

I'm getting

> hxxp://localhost:5000/user

Is it related to application or rather nginx setup?

Answer (score 0):

The thing with this setup is that the original domain name never reaches the Kestrel server and thus ASP.NET MVC doesn't know it. Instead nginx when acting as a reverse proxy makes a request to `localhost:5000` and that's why when you try to generate an absolute url from your application, it will use this instead of the original url coming from the client.

One possible way would be to configure nginx to send the original url as some custom header, but then you will need to use custom url helpers that will read this helper and generate the proper url. For this reason I would recommend you using only relative urls in your ASP.NET MVC application:

```
Url.Action("Index", "User")
```

Comment: I know that the FastCGI Protocol has special headers for this and python framework flask takes them into account when generating URLs. Is there something similar here?

Comment: I am not aware of such headers that would be taken into account automatically by the url helpers.

Comment: The problem is when I want to send emails with for example some invitation link. This has to be full url. Any hints on this?